# How to send tab from Firefox on desktop to mobile Firefox app

Tags: firefox, browser

It is possible to send tab/url from mobile firefox to desktop firefox browser, but is it possible to do it in oposite way? From desktop firefox to mobile firefox and load it automaticly like it is in other direction. 
I couldn't find any possibilities than saving bookmark.

#### Allright, now it is available in both vesions, mobile and desktop (FF v52.5, right now). Right click on tab and 'send to device'.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on tab -> send tab to device

[image: sendToDevice]

Comment: Do you know if its possible to send from Firefox Mobile browser to Computer browser? or is it currently only a feature in Computer Browser

Comment: @Niallty there is someting like paper airplane icon in tab's hamburger menu. usualli it shares something using socials, but there it sends tab to another device :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a way using the "Send Tab To Device" Add-on that can be downloaded [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/send-tab-to-device/). I found the reference from the bug discussing a similar implementation, [here.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=507471)